# Cannot calculate price for offer (Next.js) (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, math, next.js

So my client want to create an offer so every 3 Tops is 1000EGP.
So if i have 2 then its normal price
3 its 1000
4 is 1000 for 3 and 1 for normal price
6 for 2000
and so on.

```js
if (offer3Tops) {
  const tops = productDetails.filter((product) => product.category[0] === 'Tops');
  const setsOf3 = Math.ceil(tops.length / 3);
  const remainingTops = tops.length % 3;

  const discountedTotal = setsOf3 * 1000 + remainingTops * tops[0].price;

  cartTotal -= discountedTotal;
}
```

Tried using ceil but it rounds up so 2 is 1000 and so on.
tried using floor but i get 900 per set instead of 1000.

Edit :
Full Code :

```js
async function getProducts() {
        let cartTotal = 0;
      
        const productPromises = cart.map(async (item) => {
          const product = await getProduct(item._id);
          cartTotal += product.price * item.quantity;
          return {
            ...product,
            quantity: item.quantity,
            color: item.color,
            size: item.size,
          };
        });
      
        const productDetails = await Promise.all(productPromises);
      
        if (offer3Tops) {
          const tops = productDetails.filter((product) => product.category[0] === 'Tops');
          const discountedSets = Math.floor(tops.length / 3) 
          const remainingTops = tops.length % 3;
          console.log(discountedSets, remainingTops);

          const discountedTotal = discountedSets * 1000 + remainingTops * tops[0].price;
          console.log(discountedTotal);
          cartTotal -= discountedTotal;
        }
      
        setProducts(productDetails);
        setCartTotal(cartTotal);
        setOrderTotal(Math.ceil(cartTotal + shipping ));
        setLoading(false);
      }
  
      async function getCities() {
          const statesApi = await getAllStates();
          setStates(statesApi);
      }
  
      getCities();
      getProducts();
  }, [cart, shipping]);
```

Comment: surely `const setsOf3 = Math.ceil(tops.length / 3);` should be `const setsOf3 = Math.floor(tops.length / 3);` since you want sets of 3

Comment: `tried using floor but i get 900 per set instead of 1000.` where does 900 even come from in that case? `setsOf3 * 1000` will never multiply by 900

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the reply,
https://ibb.co/nR01sHg

this is what calculated, it supposed to be 1450 right? 1000 for the 3 and 450 for one? what am i doing wrong here. thanks in advance

Comment: well, yeah, I don't know what code is behind that screenshot - but clearly `1 * 1000 + 450` is 1450 - whereas, 1350 is `0 * 1000 + 3 * 450` - makes you think - it's also interesting that you `cartTotal -= discountedTotal;` so ... suggests your cartTotal WAS 1350 + 1450 = 2800 for some reason! seeing as you subtracted 1450 from something to get 1350

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :

```js
async function getProducts() {
  let cartTotal = 0;

  const productPromises = cart.map(async (item) => {
    const product = await getProduct(item._id);
    cartTotal += product.price * item.quantity;
    return {
      ...product,
      quantity: item.quantity,
      color: item.color,
      size: item.size,
    };
  });

  const productDetails = await Promise.all(productPromises);

  if (offer3Tops) {
    const tops = productDetails.filter((product) => product.category[0] === 'Tops');
    const discountedSets = Math.floor(tops.reduce((total, product) => total + product.quantity, 0) / 3);
    const remainingTops = tops.reduce((total, product) => total + product.quantity, 0) % 3;

    const discountedTotal = discountedSets * 1000 + remainingTops * tops[0].price;
    console.log(discountedSets, remainingTops, discountedTotal);
    cartTotal -= discountedTotal;
  }

  setProducts(productDetails);
  setCartTotal(cartTotal);
  setOrderTotal(Math.ceil(cartTotal + shipping));
  setLoading(false);
}

async function getCities() {
  const statesApi = await getAllStates();
  setStates(statesApi);
}

getCities();
getProducts();
```

Had to calculate quantity also.